# The cohomology of an $S_{3}$ cover of an elliptic curve ramified in one point

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, algebraic-curves

Let $E/\mathbb{C}$ be an elliptic curve. Let $C \to E$ be a Galois cover with group $G = S_{3}$ (symmetric group on $3$ elements), ramified in one point. (To clarify: there is a unique point in $E$ over which the cover is branched. Thanks Jason.) Then $C$ is a curve of genus $3$.

I want to understand $H^{1}(C, \mathbb{Q})$. The $G$-invariants are $2$-dimensional, $H^{1}(C, \mathbb{Q})^{G} = H^{1}(E, \mathbb{Q})$. Using Chevalley–Weil one can compute the representation of $G$ on the complement $H^{1}(C, \mathbb{Q})^{\perp}$. It consists of twice the $2$-dimensional irrep $V$ of $G$.

Consequently there is an action of $M_{2}(\mathbb{Q})$ on $H^{1}(C, \mathbb{Q})^{\perp}$, and in the category of $\mathbb{Q}$-Hodge structures, we obtain $H^{1}(C, \mathbb{Q})^{\perp} = H \otimes V$, where $H$ is a $2$-dimensional Hodge structure of type $(1,0) + (0,1)$, and $V$ is the $2$-dimensional irrep of $G$.

Therefore, $H$ “is” an elliptic curve (up to isogeny).

> **Q.** Can we explicitly understand the isogeny class of $H$? Is it the same as $E$?

---

One actually does not have to use the Hodge theory. The cover $C \to E$ gives rise to a map $\mathrm{Jac}(C) \to \mathrm{Jac}(E)$. The kernel $A$ is an abelian variety of dimension $2$, with an action of $M_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$. Up to isogeny, we get $A \cong \smash{E'}^{2}$. Note that $H^{1}(E', \mathbb{Q}) \cong H$ (the Hodge structure introduced above).

So, equivalently, the question is: how does $E'$ relate to $E$?

Comment: What precisely do you mean "ramified in one point"?  Do you mean that there is a unique point in $E$ over which the cover is branched?  By my computation, lying over this unique point in $E$ there are either $2$ or $3$ ramification points in $C$.

Comment: @JasonStarr — I indeed mean that there is a unique point in $E$ over which the cover is branched. Can you have $3$ points lying over it? I thought only $2$ is possible. I think the cover always factors via as a $C_{3}$-cover of a double cover of $E$. Anyway, I'm not that used to these computations, and certainly not an expert…

Comment: @jmc You can only have two points. The partitions of six which are possible are given by 2+2+2 and 3+3 a priori. You can't have 2+2+2, because then deg R = 2- 1 + 2-1 +2-1 = 3 is odd.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar — Exactly, that's what I thought. But, like I said, I'm a novice in these things.

Comment: Already the easier question when C is a genus two curve covering an elliptic curve is nontrivial.

Comment: @DanPetersen — I guess you are right. I had not really looked at similar situations yet, but maybe it casts light on the situation that I am in.

Comment: Yes, the number of preimages must be even by Riemann-Hurwitz,
so it can't be $3$.  (Alternatively: lift the usual generators of $\pi_1(E)$
to deck transformations $g,h$ in $S_3$.  Then the commutator $[g,h]$
is the lift of a cycle around the puncture.  An element of order $2$
in $S_3$ is not a commutator.)

Answer (score 2):

I am going to take a shot at partially answering this question myself. (Parts of these arguments are due to Ben Moonen, my supervisor. All errors are mine.) Any feedback is welcome!

The exact relation between $E'$ and $E$ is possibly difficult to describe more explicitly than the tautological: “given by some correspondence on $\mathcal{A}_{1} \times \mathcal{A}_{1}$”.

What I can show:

1. $E$ and $E'$ are not isogenous in general.
2. $E'$ does depend on $E$ (i.e. is not constant in $\mathcal{A}_{1}$).

---

#### Proof of claim 1

Note that the cover $C \to E$ factors as $C \to E_{1} \to E$, where

- $C \to E_{1}$ is the quotient of $C_{3} \subset S_{3}$, and
- $E_{1} \to E$ is induced $C_{2}$-cover, which is explicitly given by modding out some $2$-torsion point $P \in E_{1}[2]$.

The study of the cover $C \to E$ may hence be replaced by the study of $C_{3}$-covers $C \to E_{1}$ ramified above the origin and a $2$-torsion points such that the corresponding monodromies are inverse to each other.

If we compose $C \to E_{1}$ with the hyperelliptic quotient map $E_{1} \to \mathbb{P}^{1}$, we obtain a $C_{6}$-cover $C \to \mathbb{P}^{1}$ ramified above $4$ points. More precisely, above two of these points lies $1$ point, while above the other two there lie $3$ points. We thus have a family of cyclic covers of $\mathbb{P}^{1}$.

Ben Moonen (my supervisor) has studied [M] the Jacobian of these covers, to see if they give rise to special subvarieties of $\mathcal{A}_{g}$. In his notation, this family corresponds to ramification data $(1,5,3,3)$, which is not in his list (p.10 (p.508 in print)). By the André–Oort conjecture (in low dimension a theorem) it follows that the Jacobian of $C$ is CM only finitely many times. Since $\mathrm{Jac}(C) \sim E \times \smash{E'}^{2}$, this implies that $E \not\sim E'$, proving the first claim.

---

#### Proof of claim 2

I am not very well versed in the language of Shimura varieties, so the moduli space of elliptic curves with a marked point of order $2$ might have a standard notation. I'll just call it $\mathcal{M}$. Over this, we have a universal family $\mathcal{E}$, and over that a $C_{3}$-cover $\mathcal{C}$. We can compactify everything and look at the boundary. Obviously $\mathcal{M} \subset \bar{\mathcal{M}}_{1,2}$.

One point on the boundary of $\mathcal{M}$ can be described as follows:

- mark $\mathbb{P}^{1}$ with the points $\{0,\infty\}$,
- attach a nodal curve to the $\mathbb{P}^{1}$ at $\{1\}$.

The dual graph of this curve consists of two vertices joined by an edge; one vertex has a loop, and the other has two half-edges (corresponding to the marked points). This has a $C_{3}$-cover:

- take a $\mathbb{P}^{1}$ and attach three nodal curves to the $3$rd roots of unity.

The map on $\mathbb{P}^{1}$ given by $z \mapsto z^{3}$ is ramified at $\{0,\infty\}$, and can be extended to the nodal curves.

The dual graph contains $3$ loops (from the nodal curves), and hence the toric rank of the Jacobian is $3$. The procedure of assigning $E'$ to $E_{1}$ (described partly in the question, and partly in the proof of claim 1) gives a map $\mathcal{M} \to \mathcal{A}_{1}, E_{1} \mapsto E'$. The above example shows that if we pass to the closures $\bar{\mathcal{M}} \to \bar{\mathcal{A}}_{1}$, the map goes through the boundary of $\mathcal{A}_{1}$, and is in particular not constant. This proves the second claim.

---

#### References

[M]: B. Moonen — [Special subvarieties arising from families of cyclic covers of the projective line](http://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/documenta/vol-15/24.pdf). Documenta Math. 15 (2010), 793-819.